# C# array of different objects

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I have 2 classes B and D. I have to create an array with 4 elements 2 of type B and 2 of type D. How do I do it?

```
B o1 = new B();
D o2 = new D();
B o3 = new B();
D o4 = new D();
```

The array should be something like this:

```
array[0] = o1; array[1] = o2; array[2] = o3; array[3] = o4;
```

Comment: I'm curious - what do you need this for?

Comment: I need to study for an exam. And couldn't find the answer on google. :)

Comment: Answer would be: makes only sense, if B and D inherit from A (class or interface), then create array of A. Although B and D inherit from Object, Object has to few properties to be useful here.

Comment: `I am new to c#. I don't like it but I have to learn it. In PHP it's 10000 times easier;` I am new to PHP. I don't like it. C# is 10000 times easier ;)

Comment: @Nolonar :))) Every man with his opinion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there is no common base class other than object, you just need:

```
object[] array = new object[4];
array[0] = o1;
// etc
```

Or in a single shot:

```
object[] array = { o1, o2, o3, o4 };
```

To use the members specific to B or D, you'd need to cast when you retrieved the values from the array, e.g.

```
B b = (B) array[0];
b.SomeMethodDeclaredOnB();
```

If B and D have *common* methods, you could declare those in an interface which both classes implemented, and change the type of the array:

```
IBD[] array = new IBD[4];
array[0] = o1;
...
array[0].SomeMethodDeclaredInIBD();
```

Or:

```
IBD[] array = { o1, o2, o3, o4 };
...
array[0].SomeMethodDeclaredInIBD();
```

Finally, to address this:

> I am new to c#. I don't like it but I have to learn it. In PHP it's 10000 times easier;

I'm sure if I tried to use PHP I'd find the same experience in the exact opposite direction. Don't assume that C# is "worse" or "harder" than PHP - it's just different, and you're bound to find it harder to use a language you're not familiar with than your "comfort zone" language.

Comment: In PHP it's like this: $array = array($o1, $o2, $o3, $o4); Much simpler. After that I can do this: $array = "here is a string". And The variable array changed it's type. Simple. Elegant. Easy to find on the web :)

Comment: @PaulMoldovan: And easy to make mistakes with. Don't underestimate the power of static typing. There's a simpler way to declare and populate the array in one go in C# as well - I'll edit that in.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But after i pass this exam I'll go back to my normal life. A PHP developer. :P

Comment: @PaulMoldovan: I think it's a pity if you don't use the opportunity you're being given to expand your horizons. It's always useful to see a different perspective on development. But if this is *really* just a means to an end as far as you're concerned, that's your call. I just think you're missing out.

Comment: I have a new question and don't want to start a new topic. If i create an array and don't know the size. How do I do it? Example: B[] newArray = new B[<size>]; ??

Comment: @PaulMoldovan - You don't create an array you create a list, `List<B>`

Comment: @PaulMoldovan - [Try google (Link is how to use list in this case)](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list)

Comment: @Sayse what is the difference between List and arrays? shouldn't they be the same thing?

Comment: @PaulMoldovan, You answered that yourself in your first comment, lists don't need a size, arrays do (again try google..), sorry for the pinging, Jon

Comment: @PaulMoldovan: No, they're not the same thing at all - and if you want to ask a different question, you *should* ask it in a new post.

Comment: @PaulMoldovan: I suppose if you heavily abused the `dynamic` keyword, you could pretend that C# was a dynamically typed language.  However, this will have heavy performance penalties and will make debugging your program much more difficult.  Also, other C# developers will come after you with torches and pitchforks.

Answer (score 4):

- or use array `object[] array` of objects
- or more OOP approch:

  public class B : IHolder {
  }

  public class D : IHolder {
  }

`IHolder[]` arrays of `IHolders`

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to c#. I don't like it but I have to learn it. In PHP it's 10000 times easier;

You left out a part of the last sentence: "to make mistakes". Strong-typedness has its strengths.

You can let the classes B and D inherit from a common base class or interface like such:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    string CommonProperty { get; }
}

class B : ISomeInterface
{
    public string CommonProperty { get; }
}

class D : ISomeInterface
{
    public string CommonProperty { get; }
}

ISomeInterface[] array = new ISomeInterface[]
{
    o1,
    o2,
    o3,
    o4
}
```