# Get only values from object

Tags: c#

I'm stuck in a block of code, I'm attempting to pass an object to a chart, the actual data is being send as `{shop: 'xyz', total: 20}`, but the chart queries only `{'xyz', 20}`, thing is, the data is coming from a query in my database, which returns me those 2 values

```
List<Object> list = new List<Object>();

while (resSCIPA.Read())
{

    object shopping = resSCIPA["shopping"];
    object total = resSCIPA["total"];

    var item = new
    {
        shopping, 
        total
    };

    list.Add(item);
}
SerieDataListModel seriesAll = new SerieDataListModel()
{
    name = "Preventiva",
    data = list
};
```

the `list` is going to receive `{'xyz', 20}`, how can I achieve this info from my actual loop?

Comment: If you don't want the total, don't include the total in your object. In other words `var item = new { shopping };`...

Comment: no, the shopping = xyz, and the total = 20, I need them both without the atribute name, only their values

Comment: Oh, you want the value of shopping to be the property name?

Comment: I don't want neither property name, just their values so the chart can read the data correctly

Comment: Then you don't want an object, you want an array. Use array semantics then `var item = new dynamic[] { shopping, total }`.

Comment: What is resSCIPA? Does it not have value property. Like resSCIPA["shopping"].Value ??

Comment: thanks @HereticMonkey, the dynamic[] did the work!

Comment: This feels like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object

Comment: @Dessus Not really, since it has nothing to do with JSON... Maybe [C# array of different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17360545/215552)...?

Comment: Perhaps this is the way to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29632593/parsing-json-key-value-pairs-with-json-net/29632704

You can then filter down to just the values as wanted, and it would work with any flat JSON structure. If its nested then you would need some sort of recursion like technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want an array of values, use an array type to capture them:

```
var item = new dynamic[] { shopping, total };
```

Or an object if dynamic causes problems:

```
var item = new object[] { shopping, total };
```